# Which Windows settings to apply inside a virtual machine?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am looking for good settings to make within Windows when Windows is running as a virtual machine.

My virtual machines are used in the following environment:

- used during Software development
- used for testing purposes
- short term usage, e.g. a day or two
- snapshots with different configurations, e.g. different .NET frameworks installed

So far I apply the following settings:

- disable and delete all **restore points** and **previous versions**. Because I use snapshots, there's no need to keep additional copies of files.
- Disable **hibernation**. Because the PC will not save energy if only the VM sleeps.
- Turn off **Windows updates**. Because any installed update will be reset by reverting to a snapshot.
- Disable **drive indexing**. Because the index will be deleted when reverting to a snapshot.
- Delete the schedule for **defragmentation**. Because a defragmented guest disk is not useful inside a fragmented host file.
- Disable the 60 day **Desktop icon cleanup**. Because on a 60 days old VM, the assistent will run immediately.
- Disable check for **antivirus**. Because on a regularly reverted VM, the virus definition will always be old.
- Disable check for **backup**. Because there are no files to be backed up. Basically it's a clean operating system.

Of course we could have a lot of other settings, which are opinion-based, e.g. turn off the sounds, hide or show tray icons etc. This is off-topic.

I'm also not looking for settings to be made outside the VM, e.g. assign more RAM or processors to the VM.

**Which other settings can I make in Windows for best performance of my VM?**

Performance could mean:

- avoid annoying messages (make it convenient)
- increase speed (make it fast)
- decrease hard disk usage (make it small)

Only post answers with a reason. It should be a good reason, which would be acceptable by the majority of users (and therefore not really opinion-based).

If your proposal is OS-specific, please mention the OS version. My above settings should work for all versions from Windows XP through Windows 7.

Comment: Unless the VM is connected to the internet why do you even have security software installed?

Comment: @Ramhound: actually I don't have it installed. Windows will also complain about missing antivirus, so in any case, you can turn the antivirus warning off.

Comment: `Of course we could have a lot of other settings, which are opinion-based` - Any answer to this question is opinion based. Do whatever suits your needs.